# programmatically mount a disk image(DMG) in mac os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, mount, dmg, diskarbitration

**Q.** How to mount an apple disk image programmatically ?

My approach is similar to use disk arbitration for mounting as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461840/struggling-with-diskarbitration). I prefer not to use any command line tool.

The un-mount and eject works perfectly but the mount needs a BSD name(generally used for block file of disk). I've seen the source code for [DiskArbitrator](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator) also, this tool uses `hdiutil` in background to create the block file for the DMG.

Is there any other method/framework to create the block file for my disk image so that i can use it to mount the DMG?

I've already seen this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426063/programmatically-mount-a-disk-volume-using-only-a-given-file-path-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Hi, perhaps it's too late for an answer, but have you tried using `DADiskMount` for the mount task ? I personally looking for a way to format the dmg image in hfs+ format. do you know if there's api for that (currently i use the command-line of `newfs_hfs`.

Comment: @osxUser Yes, I've tried it. `DADiskMount` needs a `DADiskRef` and to create a `DADiskRef` you would need a bsd name. To create a bsd name you will need to use `hdiutil` command.

Comment: but does `DADiskMount` also format the volume with `HFS+` format ? Because had to use `newfs_hfs` from command line for that.

Comment: @osxUser `DADiskMount` will not format the volume as it is supposed to just mount the disk and its work is done.

Comment: @osxUser I don't think there is a direct API to format a Disk. You may want to read more about block files. File System is merely a wrapper over block files, created to provide easy access to disk write and read operations.